# CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js

I have this very simple example program. Running it in nodejs will produce a `CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory` and I wasn't able to find any node setting/switch to get that fixed. (ulimits are fine, enough physical memory available.)

```
x = new Buffer(1024*1024*1024-1);
JSON.parse(x);
```

I would expect the program to produce a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.

I tested on multiple machines and OS, so at least it looks somehow os-independent.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this error from happening?

Comment: since when `JSON.parse` parses raw buffers? also try not allocate so much space for nothing, instead try to `Buffer.concat` and `.length` to create the final buffer..

Comment: Its just my example to reproduce the issue. Use a long string with valid JSON and you end up with the same result...

Comment: well that almost `1GB` of memory instantly trying to be allocated.. If you have that kind of JSON then you try to parse asynchronously line by line or make use of streams.

Comment: Thanx, I know that... but I need random access to the resulting structure anyways, so somehow I need it in RAM. 1GB is imho far away from any interesting size and I really would like to know where that parsing limitation comes from. ... By the way: same result if you move the string directly into the source and circumvent the JSON#parse call.

Comment: Answer found: there is no way around: internal buffers in v8 can only be 1GB. (https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/objects.h&q=0x3fffffff&sq=package:v8&type=cs&l=4704) The JSON#parse seems to need a bigger buffer internally and then produces this CALL_AND_RETRY_0 (through smalloc) ...